# ZeroMQ: Router-dealer, Router not receiving data

Tags: go, zeromq

I am new to zeroMQ and am trying to create a server (with router socket bound to a local port) and a client with a dealer socket which connects to the router socket on the local port. The client sends data and exits, however nothing shows up on the router socket i.e. the Recv(0) call blocks forever. The server and client codes are as follows:

zmserver.go:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
         zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4")

func main() {

fmt.Println("Starting server")
serversock, _  := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.ROUTER)
serversock.Bind("tcp://*:5050")

identity, _ := serversock.Recv(0)
fmt.Println(identity) //nothing is printed
fmt.Println(serversock.Recv(0)) //nothing is printed
fmt.Println(serversock.Recv(0)) //nothing is printed
}
```

zmclient.go:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
         zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4")

func main(){

fmt.Println("Starting client")

clientsock, _ := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.DEALER)
defer clientsock.Close()
clientsock.SetIdentity("ID1")
clientsock.Connect("tcp://localhost:5050")  
clientsock.Send("", zmq.SNDMORE)
clientsock.Send("Hi Boss", 0)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the ready made go examples either in the [ZMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) or that [came with your binding](https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/tree/master/examples)?  Can you confirm that any of those other examples work as expected?

Comment: @Jason Yes i tried https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/blob/master/examples/rtdealer.go and it works. However my code doesn't.

Comment: Great, that helps.  Is there any chance, when you're starting up your processes, that you're starting the client first, then the server?

Comment: @Jason I first start the server, then run the client.